# OnMouseHover not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, mouseover

I have done an easy onmousehover effect and it works in all browsers, but firefox. I have stripped down the code to a bare minimum, but can't figure out whats wrong! Why doesn't the mouseover below work in firefox?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <style>
   #box {
    background:#222;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    border-radius:5px;
    }

    #box_hover {
    background:#555;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    border-radius:5px;
    }                   
    </style>    
    <script type="text/jscript">
    function mouseover() {
        document.getElementById('box').id = 'box_hover';
    }
    function mouseout() {
        document.getElementById("box_hover").id = 'box';
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box" onmouseover="mouseover();" onmouseout="mouseout();"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox doesn't like "text/jscript".  Try "text/javascript" instead.

Answer (score 0):

see this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6Hk74/) now this is work

```
<div id="box" onmouseover="mouseover();"></div>
```

and

```
#box {
background:#222;
width:400px;
height:300px;
border-radius:5px;
}

#box:hover {
background:#555;
width:400px;
height:300px;
border-radius:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `text/jscript` issue, you can change your code like this: http://jsfiddle.net/RKKvt/

Please note that `addEventListener` does not work in older versions of Internet Explorer, and you need to resort to [an hack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent) (or drop it completely and go for the old `element.onclick = function() { /* Do something here... */ };` way).

**HTML**

```
<div id='test'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#test {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100pt;
    width: 100pt;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    this.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: green;');
}, false);

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
    this.setAttribute('style', '');
}, false);
```